# Pagination getting cut off when adding download handler in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

I'm having an issue with the download handler from shiny (downloadHandler) and rendering a table using DT (using renderDataTable). When I use the download handler and render the table in my flexdashboard application, the pagination gets cut off. Thus, the user cannot switch to different pages of the table as the pagination doesn't fit the container or "the box" that renders the table. This only happens when I include the downloadHandler. If I include buttons using the extension from DT, the pagination does not get cut off. The problem is that I need to use the downloadHandler as the amount of data in my application is quite large. Please note, the example data is not representative of the size of the data. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here is the code that I'm using:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
  vertical_layout: fill

runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(pins)
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)


test_data  <- structure(list(Toys = c("Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", 
"Slinky", "Slinky", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", 
"Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo"), Manufacturer = c("Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C"), Price = c(5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 9, 6, 5.54, 7, 
9.99, 6.99, 6.75, 8, 7.99, 9.99, 7.99, 5.99, 8.99, 10.99, 9.75
), change = c(0, 16.69449082, 14.30615165, 12.640801, -33.33333333, 
-7.666666667, 0, 42.71428571, -30.03003003, -3.433476395, 18.51851852, 
-0.125, 0, -20.02002002, -25.03128911, 50.08347245, 22.24694105, 
-11.28298453), Dates = c("1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", 
"7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
names(test_data) <- c("Toys", "Manufacturer", "Price", "change", "Dates")
```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

selectInput("Toys",
            label = "Toys",
            choices = unique(sort(test_data$Toys)),
            selected = "Slinky")


selectizeInput("Manufacturer",
            label = "Manufacturer",
            choices = c("Select All",as.character(unlist(test_data %>%
                        dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
                        dplyr::arrange(Manufacturer) %>%
                        distinct()))), 
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(placeholder = 'Make a selection below'))               
```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)


observe({
if (!is.null(input$Toys)){
  updateSelectInput(
    inputId = "Manufacturer",
    choices =c("Select All", test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Manufacturer) %>%
      str_sort),
    selected = test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>% slice_head()
    )
  }
})

observe ({
  if("Select All" %in% input$Manufacturer){
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "Manufacturer", 
    selected = test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Manufacturer) %>%
      str_sort 
    )
  }
})

Toys_reactive <- reactive({
  if(length(unique(test_data$Manufacturer)) >= 1){
    Toys_reactive = NULL
    for(i in input$Manufacturer){
      subset_toys <- test_data %>% 
        dplyr::filter(Manufacturer == i & Toys == input$Toys)
      Toys_reactive <- rbind(Toys_reactive, subset_toys)
    }
  }
  Toys_reactive
})

    
```

{.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Table 1
```{r}

downloadLink('downBtn1', 'Download all data')
output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
  downloadButton("downBtn1", "Example.csv")
})

output$downBtn1 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    "Example.csv"
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(Toys_reactive(), file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)


DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE, 
          options = list(dom = 'lfrtip',
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})


```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trail and error, I have found a working solution. I have changed the overload from hidden to auto using a css chunk. This chunk makes the pagination show up when the table overflows the container.
```{css my-style, echo = FALSE}

````
.chart-wrapper .chart-stage {
    overflow: auto;
}
```
````

Entire test code with addition chunk:

---

````
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(pins)
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)


test_data  <- structure(list(Toys = c("Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", 
"Slinky", "Slinky", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", 
"Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo"), Manufacturer = c("Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C"), Price = c(5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 9, 6, 5.54, 7, 
9.99, 6.99, 6.75, 8, 7.99, 9.99, 7.99, 5.99, 8.99, 10.99, 9.75
), change = c(0, 16.69449082, 14.30615165, 12.640801, -33.33333333, 
-7.666666667, 0, 42.71428571, -30.03003003, -3.433476395, 18.51851852, 
-0.125, 0, -20.02002002, -25.03128911, 50.08347245, 22.24694105, 
-11.28298453), Dates = c("1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", 
"7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
names(test_data) <- c("Toys", "Manufacturer", "Price", "change", "Dates")
```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

selectInput("Toys",
            label = "Toys",
            choices = unique(sort(test_data$Toys)),
            selected = "Slinky")


selectizeInput("Manufacturer",
            label = "Manufacturer",
            choices = c("Select All",as.character(unlist(test_data %>%
                        dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
                        dplyr::arrange(Manufacturer) %>%
                        distinct()))), 
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(placeholder = 'Make a selection below'))               
```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)


observe({
if (!is.null(input$Toys)){
  updateSelectInput(
    inputId = "Manufacturer",
    choices =c("Select All", test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Manufacturer) %>%
      str_sort),
    selected = test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>% slice_head()
    )
  }
})

observe ({
  if("Select All" %in% input$Manufacturer){
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "Manufacturer", 
    selected = test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Manufacturer) %>%
      str_sort 
    )
  }
})

Toys_reactive <- reactive({
  if(length(unique(test_data$Manufacturer)) >= 1){
    Toys_reactive = NULL
    for(i in input$Manufacturer){
      subset_toys <- test_data %>% 
        dplyr::filter(Manufacturer == i & Toys == input$Toys)
      Toys_reactive <- rbind(Toys_reactive, subset_toys)
    }
  }
  Toys_reactive
})

    
```

{.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Table 1
```{r}



output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE, 
          options = list(dom = 'lfrtip',
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})

downloadLink('downBtn1', 'Download all data')
output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
  downloadButton("downBtn1", "Example.csv")
})

output$downBtn1 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    "Example.csv"
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(Toys_reactive()[input[["table1_rows_all"]],], file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)

tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table1", dataTableOutput("table1")))



```


### Table 2
```{r}


downloadLink('downBtn', 'Download all data')
output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
  downloadButton("downBtn", "Example.csvv")
})

output$downBtn <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    "Example.csv"
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(Toys_reactive(), file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)


DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE, 
          options = list(dom = 'lfrtip',
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})
```

```{css my-style, echo = FALSE}

.chart-wrapper .chart-stage {
    overflow: auto;
}
```
````

If anyone have has a better solution, please include it but I'll be accept this answer within the day.